# Can VLC player schedule music playing

Tags: vlc-media-player, scheduled-tasks, music

I would like to just be able to play music at a certain time, while my computer is on. Let's say I want to make a playlist start in 2 hours.

I've seen that VLC can schedule certain stuff, but I have never tried it.
Is this possible with just simple playing of files, at a certain time?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows, simply [schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task) to open your playlist.

Comment: So there is no such function in vlc, that you know of?

Comment: on linux you could use cron or sleep (time); vlc (args)

Comment: @Lasse I don't believe so, and even if there were, you would have to keep the user logged on and the application open.